# Raycasting in threeJs, when target is over object

Tags: three.js, raycasting

I'm fairly new to three.js and trying to get a better understanding of ray casting. I have used it so far in a game to show when an object collides with another on the page which works perfectly. In the game I'm building this is to take health from the hero as it crashes into walls.

I am now trying to implement a target which when hovered over some objects it will auto shoot. However the target only registers a target hit once the object passes through the target mesh rather than when its ray is cast through it.

to further detail this, the ray is cast from the camera through the target, if the target is on a mesh (stored as an object array) then I want it to trigger a function.

within my update function I have this:

```
    var ray = new THREE.Raycaster();
    var crossHairClone = crossHair.position.clone();
    var coards = {};
    coards.x = crossHairClone.x
    coards.y = crossHairClone.y
    ray.setFromCamera(coards, camera);
    var collisionResults = ray.intersectObjects( collidableMeshList );
    if ( collisionResults.length > 0 ) {
        console.log('Target Hit!', collisionResults)
    }
```

The console log is only triggered when the `collidableMeshList` actually touches the target mesh rather than when it is aiming at it.

How do I extend the ray to pass through the target (which I thought it was already doing) so that if anything hits the ray then it triggers my console log.

### Edit

I've added a URL to the game in progress. There are other wider issues with the game, my current focus is just the target ray casting.

[Game Link](https://orbitaldebris.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: Could you provide a live code example? (code snippets, jsfiddle, codepen)

Comment: Link added to game in progress, you'll need both a browser and another device to connect in order to run the game.

Comment: Just to be clear, the `Raycaster` _does_ pass through _all_ of the meshes at which it is aiming. Your `collisionResults` should be an array of all intersection points, with each point containing information about the intersection.

Comment: Thanks @TheJim01, that's exactly what I thought. My array of `collisionResults` is just an array of the meshes created. So as each wall is added into the scene it is added to the array and then created using this `var collisionResults = ray.intersectObjects( collidableMeshList );` the MeshList being an array of objects. For some reason the console log only happens once target makes contact with the Object, not when its in its sights

Comment: When are you calling this code? It sounds like you are only calling this `onMosueClick` when you should be doing it every frame in your animation loop.

Comment: Hi @XanderLuciano, Its within the update function and not on a mouse click event. It seems to console log only once the cross hair physically touches one of the objects in the `collidableMeshList` rather than when the Ray being cash has it in its sights

Comment: Try line the `lineSegment` to draw a ling in the viewer where your raycast is and just make sure it's doing what you think it's doing

Comment: @XanderLuciano great shout will give that ago.

Comment: @XanderLuciano been a while since I had the chance to look at this again. Having managed to get a line drawn in from where the Ray is cast I can see that it is not being cast from the camera's view point but rather the centre of the work space. I think perhaps I am not understanding something here in regards to setFromCamera. The ray passes perfectly through crossHair its origin is just not where the camera is. Any suggestions on where to look?

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to everyone who helped me along the way on this one but I finally solved it, only not through the means that I had expected to. Upon reading into the `setFromCamera()` function it looks like it is mainly used around mouse coards which in my instance was not what I wanted. I wanted a target on the page and the ray to pass through this. For some reason my Ray was shooting vertically up from the centre of the whole scene.

In the end I tried a different approach and set the Rays position and direction directly rather rely on setting it from the cameras position.

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3(crossHair.position.x, crossHair.position.y, crossHair.position.z);
var targetRay = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());
var enemyHit = targetRay.intersectObject( enemy );

if ( enemyHit.length > 0 ) {
    console.log('Target Hit!', targetRay)
}
```

I'll leave this up for a while before accepting this answer in case anyone has a better approach than this or has any corrections over what I have said in regards to `setFromCamera()`.